# Play Framework with dispatch(scala) : where should I install dispatch?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, scala-dispatch

I am trying to parsing JSON with scala.

So I make a scala Play Framework project. I heard if I want to use HttpUrlConnection like java, I need to import dispath classes.

I got that, but problem is I can guess where to install(?) this.

I visited dispatch homepage which explain install that library.

Link : http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html

Follows are what I did :

1. make an folder for library. names 'lib' and I put right under my project folder(where other folders are, like app, conf, target...)
2. move inside 'lib' folder and make an script like dispatch homepage says. after I command 'sbt console', I got target folder and project folder.

Now, I do not know where to put this. My Project directory looks like this.

```
test01/lib
      /project
      /app
      /target
      /logs
      /public
      /test
```

And this is under lib, which I just made to install dispatch library.

```
../../lib/build.sbt
         /target
         /project/target
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the [WS API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaWS) in the Play documentation for easy Http calls examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D Sorry I am late. Since you notice me such information, now I can control HttpConnection with scala. Anyway, I still have one more question. What is the standard way to deploy extra-library in playframework? for instance, certain folder name(which can includes naming rules. i.e. ../public/lib(s)/) or folder structure. This can be an answer to use dipatch(scala) in play. Thanks again

Comment: There is project folder and there there is a Build.scala sbt project file. You can find more at http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTDependencies Example of Hibernate dependencies: libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.derby" % "derby" % "10.4.1.3",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.9.Final"
)

Comment: Thanks for reference. I am sorry for late response :D